# Error: Call to a member function isSaleable() on null

Tags: magento2, php

I'm getting the below error:

> [2022-09-20T20:10:16.753904+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function isSaleable() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\addto\compare.phtml:32

and the line 32 was contain a code:

```
<?php if ($product->isSaleable() && $block->isRecurringEnable($product)): ?>
```

also the $product contains:

```
public function getProduct()
{
    $product = parent::getProduct();
    if ($product && $product->getTypeInstance()->getStoreFilter($product) === null) {
        $product->getTypeInstance()->setStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore(), $product);
    }
    return $product;
}
```

Comment: Check you get product details on $product I think it becomes null.

Comment: parent::getProduct() return ``null``, if this is sometimes correct then ``<?php if ($product && $product->isSaleable() && $block->isRecurringEnable($product)): ?>``